# how insert ODI step error message in to Oracle table, if the error message has single quotes and colons

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to insert ODI step error message into oracle table.
I captured the error message using `<%=odiRef.getPrevStepLog("MESSAGE")%>`.

```
ODI-1226: Step PRC_POA_XML_synchronize fails after 1 attempt(s). 
ODI-1232: Procedure PRC_POA_XML_synchronize execution fails. 
ODI-1227: Task PRC_POA_XML_synchronize (Procedure) fails on the source XML connection XML_PFIZER_LOAD_POA_DB_DEV. 
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: class java.sql.SQLException
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException: End tag does not match start tag 'tns3:ContctID'. 
    at com.sunopsis.jdbc.driver.xml.SnpsXmlFile.readDocument(SnpsXmlFile.java:459) 
    at com.sunopsis.jdbc.driver.xml.SnpsXmlFile.readDocument(SnpsXmlFile.java:469)
```

When I try to insert this into a table, I'm getting the following error:

```
Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

I tried with `substr`, `replace`. Nothing works as in middle of the error message we have a single quotes `'tns3:ContctID'`.

Is there any way to insert this into a table?

Comment: How do you tried insert it into table, could you give some snippet?

Answer (score 0):

that's a tough one if you want to use pure java BeanShell and you've given way too little details to get short and straight answer, like

- how do you try to insert this (command on source/target, bean shell only, Oracle SQL +jBS, jython, groovy etc...)

The problem here is not only quotes but also newlines.
To replace them is even more difficult as every parsing step `<%`, `<?`, `<@` requires different trick to define those literals

What will work for sure is if you write Jython task for inserting log data (Jython in technology).
There you may use Python ability for multiline string literals
simply:

```
⋮
err_log = """   
             <?=odiRef.getPrevStepLog("MESSAGE")?>
             """
⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error few days back . I applied below mentioned solution in ODI ...

Use  - q'#<%=odiRef.getPrevStepLog("MESSAGE")%>#'
This will escape inverted comma (') for INSERT statement.

I have used this in my code and it is working fine :)

For example - 
select 'testing'abcd' from dual;
this query will give below error 
"ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated"

select q'#testing'abcd#' from dual;
This query gives no error and we get below response in SQL Developer 
testing'abcd